# Problems with bisplrep and bisplev from scipy.interpolate

Tags: python, scipy, spline

I receive some quite strange behavior with `bisplrep` and `bisplev` from the `scipy.interpolate` module. I try to reproduce the example from the scipy homepage (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html). I have some function `f(x,y)` which calculates me some z-values which I then interpolate using `bisplrep`. If I recalculate the data using `bisplev` and plot the data the resulting values appear rotated about 90°. Even if I exchange the x and y values the plot is still rotated. Can somebody tell me if I am doing something completely wrong here? The following code should be sufficient to reproduce the error. I am using the most recent version of scipy and the error occurs in Jupyter, Spyder and in IDLE.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

def f(x, y):
    return x**2 + y**2

x, y = np.linspace(0, 5, 15), np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 15)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zz = f(xx, yy)

tck = interpolate.bisplrep(xx, yy, zz)

plt.pcolor(xx, yy, zz)

x_new, y_new = np.linspace(0, 5, 100), np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100)

z_new = interpolate.bisplev(x_new, y_new, tck)

plt.figure()    
plt.pcolor(x_new, y_new, z_new)

plt.figure()    
plt.pcolor(y_new, x_new, z_new)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used another definition for the grid. Now, it should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

def f(x, y):
    return x**2 + y**2

#x, y = np.linspace(0, 5, 15), np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 15)
xx, yy = np.mgrid[0:5:15j, -2*np.pi:2*np.pi:15j]
zz = f(xx, yy)

tck = interpolate.bisplrep(xx, yy, zz)

plt.pcolor(xx, yy, zz)

#x_new, y_new = np.linspace(0, 5, 100), np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 100)
xx_new, yy_new = np.mgrid[0:5:100j, -2*np.pi:2*np.pi:100j]

zz_new = interpolate.bisplev(xx_new[:,0], yy_new[0,:], tck)

plt.figure()    
plt.pcolor(xx_new, yy_new, zz_new)

plt.figure()    
plt.pcolor(yy_new, xx_new, zz_new)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have also recognized that it works when I transpose the `z_new` array (e.g. if I write `z_new.T`).